# I am getting a MultiValueDictKeyError when I'm trying to post a multiple choice form field to database

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I have a form setup that Is meant to supplement my main signup form by adding more data to the user database, It is a multiple choice form.

Here is the specifics of the error I am getting.

```
    Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/register/more

Django Version: 3.2.2
Python Version: 3.9.5
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'mainpage',
 'register.apps.RegisterConfig']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\david\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\utils\datastructures.py", line 76, in __getitem__
    list_ = super().__getitem__(key)

During handling of the above exception ('minfo'), another exception occurred:
  File "C:\Users\david\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\david\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\david\OneDrive\Desktop\Django\myapp\register\views.py", line 19, in moreinfo
    minfo = request.POST['minfo']
  File "C:\Users\david\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\utils\datastructures.py", line 78, in __getitem__
    raise MultiValueDictKeyError(key)

Exception Type: MultiValueDictKeyError at /register/more
```

It seems like it has something to do with a line in my views.py file, specifically:

```
minfo = request.POST['minfo']  

Here is the HTML file I am using: 

    <select id="minfo" name="minfo">
          <option value="C1">First country</option>
          <option value="C2">Second Country</option>
```

Comment: The error means you're trying to retrieve a key that's not in the dict-like object (`request.POST`). You haven't shown enough to say why not - there's a variety of things it could be, but basically you want to look at your HTML and how it's being generated. EG,, are you using a Django form object? If so, what's your form like? What's the form display part of your template?

Comment: I am not, I am using a basic form. I also added in the template form I have set up.

Comment: If you are not try using `request.POST.get()`.  And please post your complete html template as well as your views.py so that we can look into. There's no enough information.